# How to determine the OS version for which was compiled rpm?

Tags: linux, rpm

How can i determine the Linux version (distribution) for which was compiled rpm packet?

Comment: you mean programmatically or in general?

Comment: It's normally in the name and minor version number, e.g. .el5. for a RHEL5 or compatible, .fc13. for Fedora 13, etc. It might also be in the signing key name (e.g. "CentOS 5 signing key" or similar). Apart from that I don't think it gets encoded.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are after.

```
$ rpm -q gnome-speech --queryformat '%10{NAME} %20{VENDOR} %20{RELEASE} %20{ARCH}\n'
    gnome-speech Red Hat, Inc.                1.fc6                 i386

$ rpm -q hwdata --queryformat '%10{NAME} %20{VENDOR} %20{RELEASE} %20{ARCH}\n'
    hwdata       Red Hat, Inc.                1.el5               noarch
```

There are lots of nifty bits you can go after with queryformat, see [this guide](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-queryformat-tags.html) for a reference.
General reference on [rpm-philosophy-multi-architecture](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-philosophy-multi-architecture.html).

Comment: Almost.   I think the %{OS} tag is the one wanted, so this might be better...
`rpm -q -p myfiletotest.rpm --queryformat '%10{NAME} %10{OS} %10{VERSION} %10{RELEASE} %10{ARCH}\n'`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such ways to determine the OS name and version from the content of the file.

Normally a RPM file name contains all these details. According to the RPM file naming convention the file name must be like :

```
name-version-release.architecture.rpm
```

Please check this [link](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html) for details.

Comment: None of those are OS name and version, though? In practice it's normally it's set in the release field, e.g. release=1.el5, but that's not described on that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rpm -q` to get the OS data from the OS tag in the RPM, but you need to specify a queryformat as it is not in the normal `-i` output.  You can use `-p` to refer to a specific RPM file for the testing.

`$ rpm -q -p myfiletotest.rpm --queryformat '%10{NAME} %10{OS} %10{VERSION} %10{RELEASE} %10{ARCH}\n' 
   mypackage      linux     2.2.10   1_14.el6     x86_64`

The OS name is the second field in this output.  The RPM does not distinguish between releases of the OS though; you will only see 'linux', 'aix', 'darwin', and so on - not 'centos-6'.